# UIDatePicker changing NSLocale Issue

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker, nslocale

Hope every body is doing great.

I just came across a strange issue, changing manually NSLocale of UIDatepicker is not working but in only specific mode

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 130, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-20, 120)];  

NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:[AppDelegate getLocale]];  

[datePicker setLocale:locale];  

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

Now here it only returns hours and Minutes in English irrespective of Locale value, While if you set

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

Or even this

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Is working fine

Only when you use

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

locale is not working in that case,

Is it a bug in UIDatepicker that needs to be fixed, or what is work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got an Email/Answer from APPle that is not possible for now, may be in future.

> Thanks for contacting to Apple’s Developer Technical Support.
>
> When running in the count down mode, UIDatePicker showns the hours and minutes to count down. In this context, the “hours” and “minutes” are not a format, thus not covered by locale; rather, they are labels describing the meaning of the numbers, which honor to the application language. Note that locale is quite different from language. See WWDC 2014 Session 201 "Advanced Topics in Internationalization” for the details.

so we have to wait for that till Apple fix that :( .